# Casperjs require create empty

Tags: macos, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm new with casperjs, sure something I'm doing wrong ..
The script in docs don't print anything on screen:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('http://casperjs.org/', function() {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
});

casper.thenOpen('http://phantomjs.org', function() {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
});

casper.run();
```

Phantomjs is installed:

```
 % phantomjs --version                                                  
2.1.1
```

And casperjs:

```
 % casperjs --version                                                   
1.1.2
```

Running on OSX

Any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: Does it print anything if you simply run `console.log("something"); phantom.exit();`?

Comment: There is something wrong with your installation. I'm not a Mac user, so I can't  help you there.

Comment: I'm a Mac user but I can't find anything suspicious through your description...